# Python for-loop for asking user to enter password for 3 times

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

i want my python program to ask the user the password for three times,if user entered password is equal to the actual password with in 3 times,it should come out from the loop and print the message "Entered password is correct!" and if user enter the  wrong password ,it should print "Limit exceeded".
in my code if user enters the wrong password for three time it is showing "Limit exceeded " and"Entered password is correct!" messages.
plz help am very new to python

```
actual_pass=123

for i in range (1,4):
    pass_key = int(input('Enteer password: '))

    if(pass_key is actual_pass and i<=3):


     break
print("Entered password is correct!")

if(pass_key is not actual_pass and i>=3):

 print("Limit exceeded")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
for i in range (1,4):
   pass_key = int(input('Enteer password: '))
   if(pass_key is actual_pass and i<=3):
       print("Entered password is correct!")
       break
   elif i >= 3:
       print("Limit exceeded")
```

Answer (score 0):

What I can see here is that you are printing "Entered password is correct!" no matter the pass is correct or not... In python indentaition is really important and so your code might work if the indentation of your program is like this...

```
for i in range (1,4):
   pass_key = int(input('Enteer password: '))
   if(pass_key is actual_pass and i<=3):
       print("Entered password is correct!")
       break
if(pass_key is not actual_pass and i>3):
       print("Limit exceeded")
```